# One time divorce means it’s done after 3 months of separation?

Tags: talaq

My husband said in text msg that ‘I m giving you my first divorce’ it was 6 months back. We didn’t meet in this period and he didn’t say he took it back. And again after 4 months he said to me ‘I m happy to divorce you’
So it means I have got the divorce already ? And I can remarry according to sharia as my court case is still pending decision.

Comment: Thank u Ahmed for the answer. If anyone else has knowledge to share, please do, it may help me too.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like he want to divorce you

Divorce become final after shohor (months) aleda

So you are now free to marry again

Do your best to marry a very Good Muslim (Muslim moltazim)